# cd ~/Code && serve phpmyadmin.app /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin cause error

Tags: vagrant

i am now set up phpmyadmin for nginx server in vagrant, i have followed link : http://designinglives.net/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-vagrant-box/  .But when i am stuck in section run command line :

```
cd ~/Code && serve phpmyadmin.app /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
```

It simply return error:

```
No command 'serve' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pserve' from package 'python-pyramid' (universe)
 Command 'server' from package 'rsplib-legacy-wrappers' (universe)
 serve: command not found
```

How can i do it ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

either do

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
cd ~/Code && serve phpmyadmin.app /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
```

or simply

```
cd ~/Code && serve phpmyadmin.app /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

I think you made a mix of the 2.

*Note*

`serve` is an Homestead script to add additional site without needing to change the site file.

> Alternatively, you may use the serve script that is available on your
>   Homestead environment. To use the serve script, SSH into your
>   Homestead environment and run the following command:
>
> `serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public/directory`

see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead at *Adding Additional Sites* section.

If `serve` command is not working in your case, you might need to review the installation of Homestead

Comment: sorry, but i have done option 1, same error remain appear, I try option 2 and it almost have same error. Anybody have another idea ? I think that important thing is command **serve**  which system not found and not understand

Comment: adding comment about serve command, this is a script from homestead, review your installation and make sure the script is available

Comment: Thank you, you help me understand better for my situation, I don't use homestead, only default vagrant with ubuntu 14.04, nginx ,php mysql. Maybe i need find different way to do it .Thank you very much